# Replace a word in a string if it is in a list of words

Tags: python, string

I have the following string:

```
s = 'in may 1999, nothing really happened, same as in june 1999'

month_set = {'may', 'june', 'july'}
```

I want to replace all words that match words in the `month_set` list with the word `month`. The output should look like

> 'in month 1999, nothing really happened, same as in month 1999'

The

```
for month in month_set:
    sentence = s.replace(month, 'date')
    print(sentence)
```

but that returned the following:

> ```
> in may 1999, nothing really happened, same as in june 1999
> in date 1999, nothing really happened, same as in june 1999
> in may 1999, nothing really happened, same as in date 1999
> ```

Beside, if the above works, I need to apply it to a big list of strings which will make it slow, I think.

Comment: If speed is an issue then a regex will probably be the quickest way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = 'in may 1999, nothing really happened, same as in june 1999'
month_set = {'may', 'june', 'july'}
final_string = ' '.join("month" if i in month_set else i for i in s.split())
```

Output:

```
'in month 1999, nothing really happened, same as in month 1999'
```

A pure regex solution:

```
import re
s = 'in may 1999, nothing really happened, same as in june 1999'
month_set = {'may', 'june', 'july'}
final_string = re.sub('|'.join("(?<=\s){}(?=\s)".format(i) for i in month_set), 'month', s)
print(final_string)
s1 = 'may june mayor'
final_string1 = re.sub('|'.join("((?<=\s)|(?<=^)){}((?=\s)|(?=$))".format(i) for i in month_set), 'month', s1)
print(final_string1)
```

Output:

```
'in month 1999, nothing really happened, same as in month 1999'
'month month mayor'
```

Comment: as regex is more efficient, anyway it replaces whole words only? I want to avoid replacing `mayor` with `dateor`

Comment: @athraa You are correct, it will only replace values that make a perfect match with the strings provided in the regular expression.

Comment: can it be modified to pick whole words only?

Comment: @athraa I am not entirely sure what you mean; however, this solution will only choose whole words.

Comment: I mean in sentence like this `'may june mayor'`, the above will return `'month month monthor'`, however, I wanted it to return `'month month mayor'`

Comment: would it be easier to add that?
    `pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(month_set) + r')\b\s*')`
    `final_string = pattern.sub('month ', s)`

Answer (score 2):

Use regex:

```
import re
months = ['May', 'June']
myRegex = re.compile("|".join(months))
myRegex.sub("Month", "Welcome to May, next is June")
```

This version is case-sensitive but if you want case-insensitive version just use:

```
myRegex = re.compile("|".join(months), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `sentence` is local within the loop. On each iteration, it is assigned the value of `s` with the replacement for that iteration. Try replacing it with `s` so your changes on each iteration actually persist. ie:

```
for month in month_set:
    s = s.replace(month, 'date')
print(s)
```

Comment: Beaten to it. :)